# Firebase refuse to let me sign in from an iframe

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The website works great on mobile, but for a certain reason we need to show a mobile version of the website **inside an iframe on a desktop**.

When trying to use Firebase Authentication to sign in using Google inside an iframe on a desktop, i get this :

```
url refuse to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin
```

I understand that its due to security but how can i change the `X-Frame` options ?

Changing :     `authDomain: "xxx-xxx12.firebaseapp.com"`, **to my custom domain** didn't work. ( Google is hosting my domain)

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it , works great if not on a local server ( must deploy the app) otherwise the address is different than my domain .